# How to store cooked / stir-fried egg noodle leftovers?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, noodles, egg-noodles

I have still quite a good quantity of cooked egg noodles and I'm wondering what's the best way to store them and how long will they last? (It's mixed with chicken, bok choy, and carrots.)

And also, how to reheat them without overcooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they seem like they are kind of starchy, you might toss them with a litle toasted sesame oil. The flavor would be appropriate and that will keep them from sticking together. Other than that, just refrigerate like any other leftover. They should be good for about 4 days assuming your fridge is below 40 degrees F, as it should be. Of course they will never be as good as they were the day you made them. For reheating, my first choice would actually be the microwave. A minute at a time, tossing in between. You might need to add a tablespoon of water to help them loosen up.